# Given a complete undirected graph on n vertices, in how many ways can you choose a direction for the edges so that there are no directed cycles?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

$K_n$ be a complete undirected graph, then it has $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}$ edges. Each of these must be present in the digraph of $K_n$ and we have 2 choices for its direction. Then there are $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ digraphs. Now for each n to 3 vertices there could exist a cycle. There could be multiple cycles in a graph with say two cycles having 3 vertices and a one having 4 vertices. Out of $2^n$ possible assignments on a simple circuit for n vertices, only 2 of them will result in a cycle. So for any circuit $2^{n-1}$ non cyclic assignments are possible. These circuits will be Hamilton Circuits, and we have a complete graph. Then can I say that there are $2^{n-1}\cdot(n-1)!$ ways to choose a direction for the edges so that there are no directed cycles?

Comment: Did you try to verify your proposed formula for the case $n=3$?

Comment: You've assigned a direction to each edge of $K_n$ and the resulting directed graph has no cycles. Now define a relation $\lt$ on the vertex set: $x\lt y$ iff there is a directed edge from $x$ to $y$. What properties does this relation have? For instance, is it transitive? Is it a total ordering?

Comment: As is implicit in @user14111's comment, the answer is $n!$, not $2^{n-1}(n-1)!$.

Comment: It is both transitive and a total ordering. So do I always consider the smaller of the two relation properties(all total orderings are also transitive, and the fact that I cant count all transitive relations)? I didn't previously know that there are n! total orderings possible. Also even after I know the the correct answer, thanks to you, could you be so kind as to point the errors that I made so in future I can avoid them? Thanks.